# How to mount Windows Share on Ubuntu

Tags: permissions, mount, fstab, cifs

Currently having issues with mounting a drive to a Windows share via my Ubuntu 16.04 machine. Thoughts?

`Sudo nano /etc/fstab`:

```
//192.168.4.12/Share/Videos /media/Plex cifs 
defaults,noauto,nofail,username=Plex,password=XX,x-system.requires=network- 
online.target,vers=3.0 0 0'
```

`Sudo mount -a`

I don't receive any errors. Browsing to `/media/Plex`, I see that the folder is highlighted but can't see any media. When I do the following I get an error:

```
sudo mount -t cifs //192.168.4.12/Share/Videos /media/Plex
Password for root@//192.168.4.12/Share/Videos:  *****************
mount error(13): Permission denied
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)
```

Comment: Have you considered doing an NFS mount of this drive on your Ubuntu 16.04 machine?  If a Windows machine also uses the same partition, it can Samba mount that instead.  Just a suggestion.  If you insist on a Samba mount, have you checked that a Samba user has been created on the server (which you didn't mention about; what kind of machine is it?)?  It uses a different set of users; you need to assign a password with `smbpasswd`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I have used:

```
Where MY_WIN_NAME is my windows username
      WIN_PASSWD  is my windows login password
      192.168.1.77 is the ip address of my windows box
      SHARE_NAME   is the windows share name
      /home/myacct/m edia is the mount point:                 

mount -t cifs   -o \ user=MY_WIN_NAME,password=WIN_PASSWD,rw,hard,nosetuids,noperm,sec=ntlm \
      //192.168.1.77/SHARE_NAME  \
      /home/myacct/media
```

Comment: This is all I receive with  your code.mwolf@ubuntu-plex:/media/Plex$ sudo mount -a
mount: /etc/fstab: parse error: ignore entry at line 13.
mount: /etc/fstab: parse error: ignore entry at line 14.
mount: /etc/fstab: parse error: ignore entry at line 15.
mount: /etc/fstab: parse error: ignore entry at line 16.
mount: /etc/fstab: parse error: ignore entry at line 17.
mount: /etc/fstab: parse error: ignore entry at line 19.
mount: /etc/fstab: parse error: ignore entry at line 20.
mount: /etc/fstab: parse error: ignore entry at line 21.

Comment: I'm afraid the cut and paste did not occur properly (and I didn't notice it)... all of the backslashes (i.e. \) should have been the last character on the line it occurs... so, the easiest thing to do is simply remove all of the backslashes and concatenate the entire three lines together.

Comment: I still keep getting this error even with the changes that were made per your comment - root@ubuntu-plex:/etc# mount -a
mount: /etc/fstab: parse error: ignore entry at line 12.

Comment: Considering my instructions only consisted of 4 lines, you must have a problem elsewhere... perhaps in your /etc/fstab.... take a look at "line 12" ... or perhaps edit your original post, adding the contents of your /etc/fstab to it.  Perhaps allowing someone to spot the problem.

Comment: I got it fixed. The information you provided I guess just doesn't fit well with Ubuntu. I followed this and now my cifs is working //apollo/install_files /path/to/mnt smbfs iocharset=utf8,credentials=/path/to/.smbcredentials,gid=1234 0 0

Answer (score 0):

so you are trying to mount windows "Video" shared folder to your linux mount point /media/Plex ? in that case the error is very clear it says as below:

```
Password for root@//192.168.4.12/Share/Videos: ***************** mount error(13):
```

You see its asking for root password , where in it should have asked for user password (user on windows) to correct this you will have to execute command like:

```
mount -t cifs //192.168.4.12/Share/Videos /media/Plex --verbose -o user=username
```

in the above command you need to provide username of windows and when asked provide password of the windows user let us know if that helps :)

Waiting for your reply,

Comment: This may work but I'm looking for a permanent mount. When I do, however, use the code above I get Mount: only root can use "--options" option

Answer (score 0):

Using Ubuntu 22.04:

```
# if mount issues an error message about cifs or nfs needing a helper:
sudo apt install cifs-utils # cifs only
sudo apt install nfs-common # nfs only

# export some environment variables:
export windows_username=<windows username> # actual windows login user name
export windows_password=<windows password> # actual windows login password
export windows_share=<windows unc share path> # //192.168.1.2/c or //tailscale-system-name/c
export windows_mount_point=<windows mount point> # make sure mount point directory is already created

# example: sudo mount -t cifs -o username=$windows_username,password=$windows_password //7950x-2tb/e /mnt/e

sudo mount -t cifs -o username=$windows_username,password=$windows_password $windows_share $windows_mount_point

# now you can issue some commands. Watch out for permission issues.
# sudo cp -p -r  /mnt/e/bridge/data/data/* .
# sudo chmod 0666 -R *
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).